# Force needed to change momentum, from fixed position

Tags: kinematics, momentum, centripetal-force

I have a situation where I want to change the velocity of a mass, by applying a force from a fixed position.

For example in the diagram below, the mass starts with the initial velocity in the upper left, and it must travel through the goal point with the final velocity. The catch is, this must be effected by a repelling force applied from the 'force origin' at the bottom of the diagram.

[image]

A real-life analogy would be a boat approaching a dock, and somebody on the boat reaches out with pole and pushes the boat away from the dock, with a single steady push and only touching the dock in one place.

I need to calculate the force required at any given point during this transition. For example in this particular case if the mass was to follow the red dashed line, no force is necessary at all initially because it needs to move in a straight line for a while. During the red dashed line phase, the force will be needed, and will be strongest at the middle of that phase.

The radius of the arc is not important, although it would ideally be as large as the situation will allow.

The magnitude of the final velocity is also not important, and it does not seem like something that can be controlled anyway...

It occurs to me that during the red dashed phase the mass undergoes a centripetal acceleration toward the focal point of the arc segment (which would be a heck of a lot easier to calculate!), but how to determine the force needed to accomplish that by pushing from a fixed point on the outside of the arc, I just cannot figure out.

Comment: $F=\frac{dp}{dt}=m\frac{\vec{v2}-\vec{v1}}{dt}$

Comment: Are there any specific rules as to where the goal point has to be? Does it simply have to be somewhere on line reflected from the incoming trajectory?

Comment: The force origin and goal point are fixed constraints. The mass must pass through the goal point, having the direction of the final velocity. The path taken, and time taken to get there is not important. I'm starting to think the arc section is a bezier curve, not a semi-circle.